# C# Parse anonymous type to List of string values

Tags: c#

I have an array of such `object`:

```
object[] internationalRates = new object[] 
{ 
new { name = "London", value = 1 }, 
new { name = "New York", value = 2 } , 
etc...
};
```

I need to get `List<string>` of countries (or `Dictionary<int, string>` of pairs). How can I cast it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `dynamic` keyword in this case:

```
var result = internationalRates.ToDictionary(
                                   x => ((dynamic)x).value,
                                   x => ((dynamic)x).name);
```

This produces a Dictionary with key/value pairs.

*Warning:*

The key and value are both of type `dynamic`, which I sorta don't like. It could potentially lead to run-time exceptions if you don't pay attention to the original types.

For example, this works fine:

```
string name = result[2];  // name == "New York"
```

This will also compile just fine, but will throw a run-time exception:

```
int name = result[2];     // tries to convert string to int, doesn't work
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use `dynamic` you can write your own implementation of `ToDictionary` method with use of Reflection. Something like this :

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static Dictionary<T1, T2> ToDictionary<T1, T2>(this IEnumerable<object> dict, string key, string value)
    {
        Dictionary<T1, T2> meowDict = new Dictionary<T1, T2>();

        foreach (object item in dict)
            meowDict.Add((T1)item.GetType().GetProperty(key).GetValue(item),
                (T2)item.GetType().GetProperty(value).GetValue(item));

        return meowDict;
    }
}
```

Usage example :

```
        object[] internationalRates = new object[] 
        { 
            new { name = "London", value = 1 }, 
            new { name = "New York", value = 2 } , 
        };

        var dict = internationalRates.ToDictionary<int, string>("value", "name");

        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> item in dict)
            Console.WriteLine(item.Key + "  " + item.Value);

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Output :

1   London

2   New York

Answer (score 1):

Change your definition to this:

```
var internationalRates = new [] 
{ 
    new { name = "London", value = 1 }, 
    new { name = "New York", value = 2 } , 
};
```

And then you can use this:

```
var res = internationalRates.ToDictionary(x => x.value, x => x.name);
```

Comment: I can't change definition, because I need to work with such array. Definition in question was just an example.